# How to remove underline in Files list view?

Tags: gnome, nautilus, ubuntu-gnome

I have Ubuntu Gnome 15.04 and I've just installed Gnome 3.16. So far it's okay, except one thing:

[image]

Is there a way to remove this dotted underlining? It appears only in list view. I've tried to dig in theme styles, but these lines remain in all themes (Adwaita, HighContrast and Numix).